# cannot install bootstrap in angular

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Hello i am starting in angular i have this error when i want to install bootstrap in my project

```
npm WARN icss-utils@5.0.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-modules-extract-imports@3.0.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-modules-local-by-default@4.0.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-modules-scope@3.0.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-modules-values@4.0.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ bootstrap@3.3.7
updated 1 package and audited 1491 packages in 49.489s

78 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 moderate severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried to make `npm audit fix` but it also produce an error

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

it will take care of importing the module(NgbModule) and update your styles.scss

Answer (score 0):

For ngx bootstrap, the steps are as follows:

1- Open your terminal and use the below command to install ngx-bootstrap on your machine:

```
 npm install ngx-bootstrap
```

2-Now, you need the bootstrap CSS file. You can get it using the CDN
Alternatively, install bootstrap within the angular.json file

```
“styles”: [ 
“node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css”, 
“styles.css” ],
```